# Collapsible for sub list is not working in material design

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, materialize

I am trying to create a list having a sub-list using material design. In this when I click on sub-list header, it doesn't expands. But the main header gets expanded. I think the collapsible functionality is not working for inner header. I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>List</title>

  <link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="blue-grey lighten-5">


  <div class="center-align">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">

      <li>

        <div class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey">User Management</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#listuser">List User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#createuser">Create User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#updaterole">Update User Role</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#deleteuser">Delete User</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey">Role Management</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#addrole">Add Role</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#listofroles">Edit Role</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#deleterole">Delete Role</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your JS

Comment: I am not using any JS as of now for this. Collapsible class is defined in materialize.js file.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you haven't used any Js, it means you have not initialized the **collapsible**. In you, custom Js add the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
```

Please refer the docs carefully. 
http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

Comment: Yes I also tried adding this script. But it is working for the parent header, not for the sub-header. I am experiencing issues in expanding the sub list. By the way, Thank you.